# How return an array of objects from `result1` that are not in the` result2` array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How to compare two arrays so that they return arrays of objects that do not match. The above entry returns to me an array of objects that are in both one and the other. How do I return an array of objects from `result1` that are not in the`result2` array?

```
let result = result1.filter(o1 => result2.some(o2 => o1.id === o2.id));
```

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-qavyib

```
var result1 = [
    {id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra'},
    {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
    {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
    {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
];

var result2 = [
    {id:2, name:'John', email:'johnny@example.com'},
    {id:4, name:'Bobby', email:'bobby@example.com'}
];

let result = result1.filter(o1 => result2.some(o2 => o1.id === o2.id));

console.log(result);

/*
  0: Object
  id: 2
  name: "John"
  type: "admin"
  username: "johnny2"
  1: Object
  id: 4
  name: "Bobby"
  type: "user"
  username: "be_bob"*/
```

Comment: Have you tried negating the filter condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that `.every` item in `result2` does not have an equal `id`:

```js
var result1 = [
    {id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra'},
    {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
    {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
    {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
];

var result2 = [
    {id:2, name:'John', email:'johnny@example.com'},
    {id:4, name:'Bobby', email:'bobby@example.com'}
];

let result = result1.filter(o1 => result2.every(o2 => o1.id !== o2.id));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track.

In 2019, the contemporary approach is to use `filter()`.

To compare two arrays and return the difference you need to use the `!` (`not`) operator.

**Working Example:**

```js
var result1 = [
    {id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra'},
    {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
    {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
    {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
];

var result2 = [
    {id:2, name:'John', email:'johnny@example.com'},
    {id:4, name:'Bobby', email:'bobby@example.com'}
];

let difference = result1.filter(({ id: id1 }) => !result2.some(({ id: id2 }) => id2 === id1));

console.log(difference);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can abstract the question a bit to write a function that accepts a predicate which tells you if two values are equal, and then use that general function with a simple `(x, y) => x.id == y.id` to get a function which finds the difference you're looking for.  Something like this:

```js
const diff = (pred) => (xs, ys) => 
  xs.filter(x => !(ys.some(y => pred(x, y))))

const diffById = diff ((x, y) => x.id === y.id) 

const result1 = [{id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra'}, {id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'}, {id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'}, {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}]
const result2 = [{id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'}, {id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}]

console.log (
  diffById (result1, result2)
)
```

Comment: this only checks if id equals, what if id is the same, others props are not?

Comment: @David: That was very much intentional.  This lets you decide how you want to test equality.  I see you answered with Ramda; in Ramda (disclaimer: I'm one of the authors) this is `differenceWith`.  The one you used is `difference` which could easily be implemented as `differenceWith(equals)`.  Also note that the original code had different styles of objects in the two arrays, and the OP's sample code was also comparing by testing ids.

Answer (score 1):

One-line solution using Ramda, try it [here](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?%20%20const%20result1%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bid%3A1%2C%20name%3A%27Sandra%27%2C%20type%3A%27user%27%2C%20username%3A%27sandra%27%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bid%3A2%2C%20name%3A%27John%27%2C%20type%3A%27admin%27%2C%20username%3A%27johnny2%27%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bid%3A3%2C%20name%3A%27Peter%27%2C%20type%3A%27user%27%2C%20username%3A%27pete%27%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bid%3A4%2C%20name%3A%27Bobby%27%2C%20type%3A%27user%27%2C%20username%3A%27be_bob%27%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20result2%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bid%3A2%2C%20name%3A%27John%27%2C%20type%3A%27admin%27%2C%20username%3A%27johnny2%27%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7Bid%3A4%2C%20name%3A%27Bobby%27%2C%20type%3A%27user%27%2C%20username%3A%27be_bob%27%7D%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20result%20%3D%20R.difference%28result1%2C%20result2%29%3B%0Aresult) or below:

```
R.difference(result1, result2);
```

Note: this solution does not only check one property e.g. id, it checks all props equality.

```js
const result1 = [
{id:1, name:'Sandra', type:'user', username:'sandra'},
{id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
{id:3, name:'Peter', type:'user', username:'pete'},
{id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
];

const result2 = [
{id:2, name:'John', type:'admin', username:'johnny2'},
{id:4, name:'Bobby', type:'user', username:'be_bob'}
];

const difference = R.difference(result1, result2);
console.log(difference);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```